# Approximating a big number

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there some relatively nice way to show that $100^{100}-99^{99}>9.92\cdot 10^{199}$ by using only pencil and paper?

Comment: did you try writing $9.92=10-0.08$ and then cancelling $10^{200}$? Did it help?

Comment: No but how can I cancel the number $10^{200}$?

Comment: $100^{100}=10^{200}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Bernoulli inequality, 
$$\frac{100^{99}}{99^{99}}=\left(1+\frac1{99}\right)^{99}>2$$
(in fact it is $\approx e$), so that $99^{99}<\frac12100^{99}=0.05\cdot 10^{199}$ and finally
$$ 100^{100}-99^{99}>(10-0.05)10^{199}=9.95\cdot 10^{199}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with $99^{99} = (100-1)^{99}=100^{100}(1-\frac{1}{100})^{99}$. Then expand this using the binomial approximation. So have terms like 1-99/100 + 98*99/(100*100 * 2!) etc.
Feel there is a neater way but can't see it.